# Calling TrackPopupMenu() after a spacebar key press on CLinkCtrl causes a warning message beep. Why?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, mfc, dialog

Bear with me. I'll have to give you my setup.

I have a dialog window with a syslink-control on it ([CLinkCtrl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/clinkctrl-class?view=vs-2017)):

[image]

that can be clicked to display a context menu.

I'm now trying to set up an accessibility option for a user to press a spacebar or hit enter on the keyboard to display that context menu:

[image]

I'm using the `NM_RETURN` notification for that:

```
LRESULT CTestMfcLinkCtrlDlg::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    // TODO: Add your specialized code here and/or call the base class

    if(message == WM_NOTIFY)
    {
        NMHDR* pNmhdr = (NMHDR*)lParam;
        if(pNmhdr->code == NM_RETURN)
        {
            showMenu();
        }
    }

    return CDialogEx::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And the menu itself is shown as follows:

```
void CTestMfcLinkCtrlDlg::showMenu()
{
    HMENU hMMenu = LoadMenu(GetModuleHandle(NULL),
        MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDR_MENU1));
    HMENU hMenu = GetSubMenu(hMMenu, 0);

    if(hMenu)
    {
        HWND hParentWnd = this->GetSafeHwnd();

        CWnd* pW = this->GetDlgItem(IDC_SYSLINK1);
        CRect rcW;
        pW->GetWindowRect(&rcW);

        UINT iCmdRes = ::TrackPopupMenu(hMenu, 
            TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON | 
            TPM_VERPOSANIMATION | TPM_HORPOSANIMATION | TPM_RETURNCMD, 
            rcW.left, rcW.bottom, 
            0, hParentWnd, NULL);

        switch(iCmdRes)
        {
            //...
        }

    }

    DestroyMenu(hMMenu);
}
```

`IDR_MENU1` is taken from the resources:

[image]

So what happens is this: if the `system-link` control has keyboard focus, press spacebar or the enter (return) key on the keyboard. My context menu will be displayed, but then at the same time you will hear a message beep, what looks like with the `MB_ICONWARNING` parameter. I did some debugging and this message beep comes from the `TrackPopupMenu` call.

Any idea why is it doing it and how to prevent that warning beep?

Here's the [link](https://mega.nz/#!yXh2GSBT!dj5sqbuv_sXNJ3mS6H1mSh1J2m9JGluMlcpysgdOYw0) to VS2017 MFC solution that I was testing it on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popup menu is opened in response to `WM_CHAR` message. It seems the menu is opened before the `WM_CHAR` is fully processed. So the popup menu receives the same `WM_CHAR` message. The menu doesn't know what to do with that key and complains with annoying beep.

If you press the space bar while the menu is open, you will hear the same beep.

Solution, run the default function first:

```
LRESULT CMyDialog::WindowProc(UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT lres = CDialogEx::WindowProc(message, wParam, lParam);

    if(message == WM_NOTIFY)
    {
        NMHDR* pNmhdr = (NMHDR*)lParam;
        if(pNmhdr->code == NM_RETURN)
        {
            showMenu();
        }
    }

    return lres;
}
```

Or, do this in response to `ON_NOTIFY`, but make sure to remove the message from the thread by using

```
PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR, PM_REMOVE);
```

Example:

```
void CMyDialog::showMenu()
{
    CMenu menu;
    menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1);
    ASSERT(menu.GetSafeHmenu());
    CMenu *popup = menu.GetSubMenu(0);
    ASSERT(popup);

    CRect rc;
    CWnd *syslink = GetDlgItem(IDC_SYSLINK1);
    ASSERT(syslink);
    syslink->GetWindowRect(&rc);

    MSG msg;
    if (::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR, PM_NOREMOVE))
        AfxGetThread()->PumpMessage();

    UINT iCmdRes = popup->TrackPopupMenu(
            TPM_TOPALIGN | TPM_LEFTALIGN | TPM_LEFTBUTTON |
            TPM_VERPOSANIMATION | TPM_HORPOSANIMATION | TPM_RETURNCMD,
            rc.left, rc.bottom, this);

    switch(iCmdRes)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, wow. That's a cool solution. Actually simply discarding it as such `::PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_CHAR, WM_CHAR, PM_REMOVE);` does the trick. Just from the curiosity, how could you figure it out so quickly?

Comment: Well, it took me about half hour to figure it out. `PeekMessage` shows there is a `WM_CHAR` in `msg.message`

Comment: Well, I appreciate it. I was just curious to learn what tools you used for that, if any? If you don't mind [here's my email](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843732/c00000fd?tab=profile).

Comment: I didn't use any special tools. I have run in to similar problems before, this was partly a guess.

Comment: Ist't calling `showMenu` from `WindowProc` somewhat fishy anyway?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: why so?

Comment: @c00000fd just an impression, but I may be (and probably am) wrong.

Comment: @Jabberwocky: Well, normally you wouldn't be doing it manually. MFC class wizard can add its own override from the IDE, but it won't be very descriptive if I used it here. (It will have a name like: `void CMyDlg::OnNMReturnSyslinkControlName(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)`.) That is why I decided to unfold it into "pure" Win32.

Comment: @Jabberwocky We are not supposed to override `CWnd::WindowProc` in general, because it calls `CWnd::OnWndMsg` and it runs additional MFC initialization for some messages. Looking at the source code in wincore.cpp, it doesn't do anything special for `WM_NOTIFY`, it should be okay to override it in this case, as long as we don't override `OnNotify` and related messages. It's useful for testing, I would otherwise leave it alone.